# Node server not working with webcomponents-loader js

Tags: node.js, polymer

I want to use node.js to connect to socket.io and my front end is using polymer start kit. However, when I use node to host the website, webcomponents-loader.js is not working. Here is the error message. 
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZXBL.png)

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Can you post the code please?
Are you sure you have installed webcomponents-loader? If not, do this: `npm install web-components-loader --save`